# Why does Xcode 10 in Playground not run automatically?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

I'm studying Swift and in the course I'm following on Udemy or even in videos found on the Internet when they use Playground, the code is executed automatically.

Is it possible to enable this feature even on the latest version?

Currently used version: 10.2.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43144667/1187415

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I believe you mean this:
Click and hold the run button and select Automatically run.

[image]

Comment: Yeap this is it. The magic everyone is wondering in the first time. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Try to check the play/stop button on the bottom of the editor and make sure it's set to **Automatically Run**.

[image: Xcode Automatically Run]